# BIG_INT error with UcanAccess and Java

Tags: java, database, ms-access, ms-access-2010, ucanaccess

I tried to connect a db only to try UcanAccess like an example that I found here, but it doesn't work, it has a BIG_INT error, I don't know how to fix it; I work on java8, I have added commons-lag 2.6, commons-logging 1.1.1, hsqldb 2.1.4, jackaccess 2.1.6 and ucanaccess 4.0.4, I work on win10 here the code:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class MsAccessDatabaseConnectionInJava8 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // variables
        Connection connection = null;
        Statement statement = null;
        ResultSet resultSet = null;

        // Step 1: Loading or registering Oracle JDBC driver class
        /*try {

            Class.forName("net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver");
        }
        catch(ClassNotFoundException cnfex) {

            System.out.println("Problem in loading or "
                    + "registering MS Access JDBC driver");
            cnfex.printStackTrace();
        }*/

        // Step 2: Opening database connection
        try {

            String msAccDB = "C:/Users/utente/Documents/Prova.accdb";
            String dbURL = "jdbc:ucanaccess://" +msAccDB; 

            // Step 2.A: Create and get connection using DriverManager class
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL); 

            // Step 2.B: Creating JDBC Statement 
            statement = connection.createStatement();

            // Step 2.C: Executing SQL &amp; retrieve data into ResultSet
            resultSet = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM PLAYER");

            System.out.println("ID\tName\t\t\tAge\tMatches");
            System.out.println("==\t================\t===\t=======");

            // processing returned data and printing into console
            while(resultSet.next()) {
                System.out.println(resultSet);
            }
        }
        catch(SQLException sqlex){
            sqlex.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally {

            // Step 3: Closing database connection
            try {
                if(null != connection) {

                    // cleanup resources, once after processing
                    resultSet.close();
                    statement.close();

                    // and then finally close connection
                    connection.close();
                }
            }
            catch (SQLException sqlex) {
                sqlex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And these are the errors:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: BIG_INT
    at net.ucanaccess.converters.TypesMap.<clinit>(TypesMap.java:91)
    at net.ucanaccess.converters.LoadJet$FunctionsLoader.addFunctions(LoadJet.java:125)
    at net.ucanaccess.converters.LoadJet$FunctionsLoader.loadMappedFunctions(LoadJet.java:237)
    at net.ucanaccess.converters.LoadJet$FunctionsLoader.access$3100(LoadJet.java:74)
    at net.ucanaccess.converters.LoadJet.loadDB(LoadJet.java:1557)
    at net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver.connect(UcanaccessDriver.java:218)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:270)
    at controller.MsAccessDatabaseConnectionInJava8.main(MsAccessDatabaseConnectionInJava8.java:37)
```

Comment: i have tried also without comment in the first try/catch segment of course...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not using the correct dependencies for UCanAccess 4.0.4. They are:

- commons-lang-2.6
- commons-logging-1.1.3
- HSQLDB 2.3.1
- jackcess-2.1.11